# API for Google Ad Preview & Diagnosis tool

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

im new to google apis and want to know if one one such exists for `Ad Preview & Diagnosis tool`.

https://adwords.google.com/apt/AdPreview?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000

User will enter the search terms & other additional options and click on Preview. This will show list of links and user wants to know the position of a particular website in a page.

For eg: search for Guitar lessons (United States), youtube.com is in position 1 of page 1.

I want to automate this process using Asp.net C#, using the API.

Any other pointers are much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such API. Also, in October 2015 (next month as I write this) anonymous access to the Ad Preview Tool will no longer be supported; you will need to log in with an AdWords account to use the tool.

Comment: While there is still no API, in the past month or so Google has announced that the logged-out version of the Ad Preview Tool will continue to be supported.